# How to compare if the cpu serial is correct

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I have a question. I would like to check when the linux system starts or if the serial cpu is correct.
If not, he would be rebooting. So he would be doing reboot loops all the time.
I found the command to check the serial cpu command:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

How to compare the result of this command to the value of eg 000000ddd0d0d??
And I do not know how to look like such a check script and where to put it in the Ubuntu system (/etc/init.d/rc.local ??).

It is correctly??:

```
#!/bin/bash
STR=cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2
if $STR != '000000ddd0d0d'; then
reboot
```

Thank you for your help
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?  Show us the exact output your command (the value of STR).

Comment: It works: `#!/bin/bash
STR=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
case $STR in
 000000ddd0d0d) reboot;;
 default) echo "Unknown CPU ID of $STR";;
esac`

Answer (score 0):

You probably should do the whole thing in one `grep` command:

```
grep -q '^Serial.*000000ddd0d0d' /proc/cpuinfo || reboot
```

This will reboot unless a line with `Serial` and `000000ddd0d0d` in it is found in `/etc/cpuinfo`.

**BUT** this is questionable for several reasons.

1. What should a reboot be good for in such a case?  As this is supposed to be done during machine startup, you will then enter an infinite loop of reboots which can only be stopped by switching the computer off.  **This is horrible!**  You probably never encountered such a problem (as admin) or you wouldn't produce it voluntarily.  The only way to fix such a system is to boot it via some other medium (USB thumb drive or similar).
2. Not all Linux distributions or kernel versions offer a CPU serial number in `/proc/cpuinfo`.  My current system, for instance, doesn't.  So on my computer this would not work at all.
3. The whole idea of reacting on a CPU serial number is highly questionable as a CPU might break (not likely but possible) and then probably is replaced and the new CPU, while surely having a different serial number, should not pose any trouble.

So, I think [you might want to reconsider](https://youtu.be/kiiGJq4IFvo).